# Node JS, express-session, remove cookie from client browser

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies

I work with app, that already has its own infrastructure. The task is to prevent user login in several browser. Our application has single app architecture, so ideally user should work only in one browser tab. And I have a problem. I can’t remove cookie from client.

I. Briefly.

App settings:

Server: NodeJS
Port: 8083

Client: VueJS
Port: 8088

I use module `express-session` to initialize session mechanism on server side and send cookies to client. Client hasn’t set cookies.

II. Details:

Server’s root file is **index.js**

I do the following in it:

1. Plug in `express` module:

```
const express = require('express')
```

2. Plug in `cors` module:

```
const cors = require('cors')
```

3. Add `cors` settings:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:8088',
    credentials: true
}))
```

Then I initialize session in **user.js** file and receive client’s connects:

1. Plug in `express-session` module:

```
const session = require('express-session')
```

2. Plug in routing by `express.Router()`:

```
const router = express.Router()
```

3. Add session settings:

```
const EIGHT_HOURS  = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 8
const {
    SESS_NAME = 'sid',
    SESS_LIFETIME = EIGHT_HOURS,
    SESS_SECRET = 'test',
    NODE_ENV = 'development'
} = process.env
const IN_PROD = NODE_ENV === 'production'
```

4. Initialize session:

```
router.use(session({
    name: SESS_NAME,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: SESS_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: SESS_LIFETIME,
        sameSite: false,
        // Must have HTTPS to work 'secret:true'
        secure: IN_PROD
    }
}))
```

5. Receive client queries by `router.post()`

So what I did:

1. I use `req.session.destroy` to remove session data and expect the browser logout user from certain browser and cookies clear.

```
req.session.destroy(err => {
            if (err) {
                return res.send({ error: 'Logout error' })
            }
            res.clearCookie(SESS_NAME, {path: '/'})
            return res.send({ 'clearSession': 'success' })
        })
```

Unfortunately nothing magic happens

2. I read different topics. For example, here ([GitHub](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/507)) offer the conclusion: use explicit cookie’s path indication in `res.clearCookie` method as shown above.
   That didn’t work.
3. Wrote this setting `{path: '/'}` in cookies settings. Didn’t work too.

```
router.use(session({
    name: SESS_NAME,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: SESS_SECRET,
    cookie: {
    path: '/',
        maxAge: SESS_LIFETIME,
        sameSite: false,
        // Must have HTTPS to work 'secret:true'
        secure: IN_PROD
    }
}))
```

And as wrote in express-session documentation ([NPM:express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)) this path is the default path for cookie storage.

4. Add `req.session = null` in req.session.destroy:

```
req.session.destroy(err => {
            if (err) {
                return res.send({ error: 'Logout error' })
            }
            req.session = null
            res.clearCookie(SESS_NAME, {path: '/'})
            return res.send({ 'clearSession': 'success' })
        })
```

That didn’t work

5. `delete req.session` doesn’t work too.

So, how can I resolve this problem? What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

adding `.send('cleared cookie')` made my browser clear its cache of the named cookie.

```
const logOutRequest = (req, res) => {
      req.session.destroy((err) => {
         res.clearCookie("notcookie").send('cleared cookie');
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the exact cookie by setting it to null that is lets say that you are dealing with a cookie named Views you could remove the cookie using `req.session.Views = null`

Instead of doing this

```
req.session.destroy(err => {
            if (err) {
                return res.send({ error: 'Logout error' })
            }
            req.session = null
            res.clearCookie(SESS_NAME, {path: '/'})
            return res.send({ 'clearSession': 'success' })
        })
```

you could do the name of your session cookie and set that to null that is

```
req.session.sid= null
```

Comment: Oh, could you, please specify where I should write this `req.session.Views = null` line? And when you say **Views** do you mean something like `name: SESS_NAME` in session settings, i.e. I must write `req.session.SESS_NAME = null`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Session doesn't clear. The line `req.session.SESS_NAME = null` only add the new field in session store. It looks like this: `Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-10-10T21:08:28.940Z,
     originalMaxAge: 28800000,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: false,
     sameSite: false },
  userId: 1,
  blocked: 0,
  status: 'lambda',
  SESS_NAME: null }`

Comment: Sorry I've seen your session name is 'sid' try setting that to null that is req.session.sid = null

Comment: Once again unfortunately. Explicitly added SESS_NAME in line `req.session.sid = null` and got the same result as earlier. Just new line in session store: `Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-10-10T21:38:26.600Z,
     originalMaxAge: 28800000,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: false,
     sameSite: false },
  userId: 489,
  login: 'glebtregubov',
  password: '10293221',
  blocked: 0,
  status: '392',
  sid: null }`

Comment: So nothing has changed

Comment: Are you using the latest version of express-session

Comment: Yes I'm using the latest version of express-session module. Checked this by calling terminal command `npm list --depth=0`. My version is 1.16.2      `├── body-parser@1.18.3
├── chalk@2.4.2
├── cors@2.8.5
├── express@4.17.1
├── express-session@1.16.2
├── jsdoc@3.6.2
├── jsonwebtoken@8.5.1`

Comment: `res.cookie('connect.sid', '', {expires: new Date(1), path: '/' });` this is the last thing I thought of try setting the expiry date to a past date or either 

Delete cookie using below lines

`res.clearCookie('connect.sid', { path: '/' });` or `req.logOut();`

Comment: Oh, thanks, I'll try to follow these steps. Could you specify where in code I need to do this? Right in `req.session.destroy` section, yes? Like: `req.session.destroy(err => {
            if (err) {
                return res.send({ error: 'Logout error' })
            }
     res.cookie('connect.sid', '', {expires: new Date(1), path: '/' })
            res.clearCookie(SESS_NAME, {path: '/'})
            return res.send({ 'clearSession': 'success' })
        })` . And 'connect.sid' line means, that I must rewrite the line with my settings like `res.cookie(SESS_NAME, {expires ... etc)`?

Comment: Yes you would need to substitute the max age for cookie.expires and try both including it in `req.session.destroy `or substituting `req.session.destroy` with the above comment

Answer (score 0):

This removes the cookie from client browser

```
req.session.destroy(err => {
    res.clearCookie("session-cookie-name", { path: "/" });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The most important key is setting 'domain' in the clearCookie method to solve your issue. Expressjs will return the following in the http response header. However, it seems that on the browser or some browsers that I tested, it doesn't know which cookie belonging to which domain to clear, hence, the cookie remains there. You do not need to include the path when calling clearCookie

```
Set-Cookie: mycookie=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
```

You have to set domain like below:

```
 req.session.destroy(err => {
        res.clearCookie("session-cookie-name", { domain: 'your-domain' });
    });
```

Then response header will become

```
Set-Cookie: mycookie=; Domain=your-domain; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
```

The browser will clear the cookie nicely!

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```js
@Post('signout')
async signout(@Req() req: Request, @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: Response) {
  const user = req.user

  if (!user) return {}

  await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        res.clearCookie('ACCESS_TOKEN', {
          domain: '.xxx.com'
        })
        res.clearCookie('REFRESH_TOKEN', {
          domain: '.xxx.com'
        })
        res.clearCookie('connect.sid', {
          domain: '.xxx.com'
        })

        resolve()
      }
    })
  })

  return {}
}
```